# C++ Override Syntax

Tags: c++, abstract-class, intel, overriding, perceptual-sdk

I'm working with Intel's PCSDK, there's a part I don't syntactically understand from a sample where the constructor of an abstract class is overridden. Specifically, this line:

```
GesturePipeline (void):UtilPipeline(),m_render(L"Gesture Viewer") {
EnableGesture();
}
```

What does the comma between UtilPipeline() and m_render mean? Here's the entire code for context:

```
#include "util_pipeline.h"
#include "gesture_render.h"
#include "pxcgesture.h"
class GesturePipeline: public UtilPipeline {
public:
GesturePipeline (void):UtilPipeline(),m_render(L"Gesture Viewer") {
EnableGesture();
}
virtual void PXCAPI OnGesture(PXCGesture::Gesture *data) {
if (data->active) m_gdata = (*data);
}
virtual void PXCAPI OnAlert(PXCGesture::Alert *data) {
switch (data->label) {
case PXCGesture::Alert::LABEL_FOV_TOP:
wprintf_s(L"******** Alert: Hand touches the TOP boundary!\n");
break;
case PXCGesture::Alert::LABEL_FOV_BOTTOM:
wprintf_s(L"******** Alert: Hand touches the BOTTOM boundary!\n");
break;
case PXCGesture::Alert::LABEL_FOV_LEFT:
wprintf_s(L"******** Alert: Hand touches the LEFT boundary!\n");
break;
case PXCGesture::Alert::LABEL_FOV_RIGHT:
wprintf_s(L"******** Alert: Hand touches the RIGHT boundary!\n");
break;
}
}
virtual bool OnNewFrame(void) {
return m_render.RenderFrame(QueryImage(PXCImage::IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH),
QueryGesture(), &m_gdata);
}
protected:
GestureRender m_render;
PXCGesture::Gesture m_gdata;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) which initializes the base class and a member variable:

```
GesturePipeline (void) // constructor signature
  : UtilPipeline(), // initialize base class
    m_render(L"Gesture Viewer") // initialize member m_render from GesturePipeline
{
    EnableGesture();
}
```

Comment: Why does `m_render` need to be initialized this way?

Comment: @Mike There are several reasons why something must be initialized in the initializer list: 1) Because it's a reference 2) Because it can not be default-initialized 3) Because the member variable is declared `const`. In your case I'd think it's probably 2). Of course it might just be used because it's more efficient and it's considered preferable by many, even if default-construction and an assignment later would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 1):

That's the constructor's initialiser list, used to specify how to initialise base sub-objects and data members before the constructor body begins.

This one value-initialises the base sub-object, then initialises the `m_render` member by passing a string to its constructor. The other data member is default-initialised, since it doesn't appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [member initializer list.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
GesturePipeline (void):UtilPipeline(),m_render(L"Gesture Viewer") {
EnableGesture();
}
```

first initializes the base class with it's default constructor `UtilPipeline` then initializes `m_render` with `m_render(L"Gesture Viewer")`. Lastly it enters the function body and executes `EnableGesture()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an initialization list. You are initializing that element in the class. [Quick tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html). The comma is separating the elements that you are initializing. It is calling the base constructor and then initializing its own elements.